# What is the power series for a half-exponential function?

Tags: asymptotics, power-series

What is the power series of a half-exponential function?

Half-exponential means that $f(f(x)) = y^x, y > 1$

Comment: This appears closely related to two earlier questions regarding the half-iterates of [$e^x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65876/) and [$2^x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868591/).

Comment: what is $\Theta$?  If you just mean $f(f(x))$ remains within a bounded factor of $y^x$ I don't see why there should be _one_ power series.  If you mean $f(f(x))=y^x$ you can get the first few terms of the series by expanding and equating coefficients.

Comment: @SilvioLevy deleted the unnecessary big-theta