# Changing the base of an exponential function

Tags: computer-science

I don't follow the last step mentioned in the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860482/examples-of-sub-exponential-functions-that-arent-exponential-functions-when-cha/860496#860496?newreg=0df6b3772cfc470e9ad5ff37637b488c)

Why is does this hold? 
$$n^{k^2\log n}=2^{k^2\log^2n}$$

I would have posted this question as a comment on the post, but apparently I don't have enough reputation points to do that...

Answer (score 1):

taking the logarithm of both sides we get
$$k^2\log(n)\log(n)=k^2(\log(n))^2\log(2)$$ for $k\ne 0$ and $\log(n)\neq 0$ we get
$$\frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}=\log(n)$$ we must specify that $\log(n)=\log_2(n)$
then we get
$$\log_2(n)=\log_2(n)$$

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand it now. To get from the left side of the equation to the right side, the following substitution is being done:
$$n = 2^{\log_{2} n}$$
And all of the logarithms are base 2. So then:
$$n^{k^2\log_{2} n}=(2^{\log_{2} n})^{k^2\log_{2} n}$$
which becomes:
$$2^{(\log_{2} n) k^2\log_{2} n}$$
which is:
$$2^{k^2(\log_{2} n)^2}$$
which is the same as:
$$2^{k^2\log^2 n}$$
(where the base of the logarithm is 2).

Thanks for all  of the replies!

Answer (score 0):

It should be $$n^{k^2\ln{n}}=\left(2^{\log_2n}\right)^{k^2\ln{n}}=\left(2^{\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln2}}\right)^{k^2\ln{n}}=2^{\frac{1}{\ln2}k^2\ln^2n}$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am not wrong here, if I take 2 as the base of the natural logarithm:$$2^{{log_2 n}^{k^2 log n}}=2^{k^2(logn) (log n)}=2^{(logn)^2 k^2}$$